# What is this drawing style that faces the x-y plane but stylisticly pulls the z axis down and to the left?

Tags: drafting

[image]

Notice that x and y are proportionally equal and perpendicular to your line of sight, but z is not. It's not [30-90-30 isometric](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&sa=1&q=30+90+30+isometric&oq=30+90+30+isometric&gs_l=psy-ab.3...6851.10894.0.11955.9.9.0.0.0.0.677.1055.3-1j0j1.2.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..7.2.1055...0i7i30k1j0i8i7i30k1j0i8i13i30k1j0i8i30k1.0.uGMqTquNgo4). Also z should actually be pointing right at you rather than down and to the left if this was true 3D rendering. Hence this is a style. Does it have a name?

Note: z is free to scale any way you like so this style can be made into a kind of isometric. That is x, y and z can all have the same scale. But regardless of that does this have a name that wont be confused with 30-90-30 isometric?

Answer (score 3):

This appears to be a **Cavalier projection** since the oblique lines are at the same scale as the xy plane. The name comes from military fortifications - a "cavalier" was the French term for an artificial mound behind a defensive wall, which allows the enemy to be seen over the wall. As the name might suggest, a low "*cavalier*" provided a relatively risk-free way for a *cavalry* unit to see over the defensive wall. The projection was intended to show such a view.

The equal scaling of all three axes makes this easy to draw, but the result is not necessarily very "realistic".

There is a similar *Cabinet projection* which was commonly used in illustrations of furniture, etc. In a cabinet projection the oblique lines are shortened in a "simple" proportion like 2:1 or 3:2, for easy drawing and greater realism.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oblique_projection, which has some illustrations of both projections.

Comment: Note, as a French term the pronunciation is presumably "ka-VAL-ee-ay," not the English "ka-va-LEER".